# Entry Cursor not centered

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using a Entry for my Application.

When the Entry is Empty the cursor doesnt center.
Im using a Custom Renderer with the following code:

```
if(this.Control != null) {
    Control.Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterVertical;
    TextAlignment = Android.Views.TextAlignment.Center;
    Control.TextAlignment = Android.Views.TextAlignment.Center;
```

But none of these  fix my problem.The Problem looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Its not a perfect solution but to get out of this issue, you can reduce the height of your entry control by making it fixed like: `HeightRequest="50"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use SetPadding property that will definitely work for you

```
Control.SetPadding(0,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this might help you

```
 <Entry Placeholder="Benutzer" 
   VerticalOptions = "LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand"/>
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work. Thank you for your answer tho

Answer (score 0):

I did a little workaround. I just don't display the cursor when my Entry is empty.

```
            if (this.Control.Text != "")
            {
                this.Control.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
            }
            else
            {
                this.Control.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            }
```